# iptables redirect all requests to localhost

Tags: debian, iptables, hosts

I want to redirect all requests made to a particular ip to localhost (127.0.0.1). I need it because I have a local replica of a server and want to test some things

How can I write a iptables rule to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean "I want all requests made from machine A to machine B, to be redirected to machine A"? If so, I believe the command you are looking for is

```
sudo iptalbes -t nat -A PREROUTING -d <DESTINATION_IP> -p <PROTOCOL> --dport <DESTINATION_PORT_NUMBER> -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Sorry.. My bad. You also need to enable IP forwarding. echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

Comment: OK. then I have no clue! sorry about that.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp ''otherconditions'' -j TPROXY --on-port ''dst''
```

Quoting manpage: *This target is only valid in the mangle table, in the PREROUTING  chain
       and user-defined chains which are only called from this chain. It redi-
       rects the packet to a local socket without changing the  packet  header
       in any way.*

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty old thread... But still without an answer. The main change required will be to append an OUTPUT rule rather than PREROUTING rule.

From the man page:

```
nat:
    This table is consulted when a packet that creates a new connection is encountered.  It consists of three built-ins: PREROUTING (for altering packets as soon as they come in), OUTPUT (for altering locally-generated packets  before  routing),  and  POSTROUTING  (for altering packets as they are about to go out).
```

So, this might be the command required:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --src <SOURCE PORT TO BE REDIRECTED> --dst 127.0.0.1 --dport 9090 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9090
```