# Unable to connect to dockerized postgres on localhost, but remote connection is working

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking, docker-network

I created docker postgres instance with

```
docker run -d \
  --name test_db \
  -v data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  -e "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=abcdefghij" \
  -e "POSTGRES_USER=testuser" \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  postgres
```

I can properly connect to this database from other hosts using public server ip, eg.

```
 psql -U testuser -h 111.111.111.111 -d testuser   // in reality I use proper IP
```

but if I want to do this on the same host where container is running, it's impossible to connect (it just hangs).

My pg_hba.conf (inside container)

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust    
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

Inside postgresql.conf there is a line:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Relevant lines of iptables:

```
$ iptables -L | grep sql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.2           tcp dpt:postgresql
```

Also, it works locally if I use 172.19.0.2 address, but if I use public server IP it just hangs. I have no idea why it's the case. I have my application distributed among many hosts, including one with DB, and I don't want to use other address depending on location. Can somebody help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely not Docker and from what you are describing is the configuration of your (company) network that routes packets to 111.111.111.111 towards the default gateway. I suspect that the public ip 111.111.111.111 is your IP behind a NAT.

For short 111.111.111.111 will not get mapped to 127.0.0.1 since the binding is made somewhere outside your computer.

You would want to do something like this [iptables redirect all requests to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583004/iptables-redirect-all-requests-to-localhost)

Comment: Two test servers are just normal clean VPS on ArubaCloud. I'm not sure if there are any NAT involved, but it shouldn't be. I'll try redirecting with iptables and say if it worked.